# How to update latest version of Parse Server on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, parse-server

How can I update latest version of Parse Server however I am using parse Example server on Ubuntu where is my installed server version is **2.2.12** and at this time the new release parse server version is **2.2.15**, I know how to update Parse server but did not know how to update it using parse example server.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using it in a specific project, you need to edit the `package.json` file and make sure that `"parse-server": "~2.2.15"` is under the `dependencies` section. Then you will need to rerun `npm install` in the project's directory.

Otherwise for the global configuration (across the whole server assuming no `package.json` is overriding it)

Run `sudo npm install -g parse-server@2.2.15` in the terminal for the specific version.

Or `sudo npm update -g parse-server` for update it the latest version (if it is already installed).